# jquery load invocation results in empty query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, jquery-load

I have this file: "myFile.html" where I simply want to display the value of xxx from the query string. I extracted the following with the help of other threads. I used purl and also a custom function.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/purl.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.debug($.url().param('xxx'));
    console.debug(getParameterByName('xxx'));
}); 

function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
</script>
```

Invoking the url from firefox: "localhost..../myFile.html?xxx=hi" works fine and the value of xxx gets displayed in the console both with purl and the custom function.

However, if I load "myFile.html" through JQuery.load within another page "myHome.html" the value of xxx results in an empty string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myDiv').load("myFile.html?xxx=hi");
}); 
</script>
```

I can´t figure out why is that...

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior you are seeing is expected because all you are doing with the line

```
$('#myDiv').load("myFile.html?xxx=hi");
```

is dumping the raw HTML into the myDiv div tag. The containing page's URL is unaffected by this action. Therefore, your call to the xxx query string parameter doesn't return anything because that parameter is embedded in the div tag, not appended to the query string.

Comment: do you have any workaround? I need that value at the time myFile.html gets loaded into the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:
[jquery get querystring of loaded page in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180841/jquery-get-querystring-of-loaded-page-in-a-div)

it seems not possible, but using the callback function I overcame the issue.